# Angular 5 Select option not selected [selected]

Tags: angular, selected

When i write

```
[selected]="b.brokerId=='1110'"
```

in my ngFor the values is not coming as selected in my component HTML file

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedContactFilters.brokerSelected" (change)="onBrokerChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let b of broker; let i = index" [value]="b.brokerId" [selected]="b.brokerId=='1110'">{{b.brokerName}}</option>
</select>
```

when i write condition

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedContactFilters.brokerSelected
```

has to have value of '1110' for it to work, you don't need `[selected]` attribute.

here is a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/HHGyCYod1KD1wV4PAYFu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In the component where you getting the `broker` info there only add this line

```
selectedContactFilters.brokerSelected = '1110';
```

or

```
selectedContactFilters = {
    brokerSelected : '1110'
}
```

Guessing the format, one out of above 2.